# JSON to XML Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've been using Json.Net to parse JSON to object and convert to XMLDocument but I got

> InvalidOperationException This document already has a
> 'DocumentElement' node.

I have this JSON data:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Eros Harem",
         "id": "2345123465"
      },      
      {
         "name": "Vincent Dagpin",
         "id": "56783567245"
      },
      {
         "name": "Vrynxzent Kamote",
         "id": "3456824567"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "nextURLHere"
   }
}
```

and this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonToXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText("friends.json");

            // To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node
            XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
        }
    }
}
```

did i miss some settings?

I expect to have something like this as output.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<friends>    
    <data>
        <name>Eros Harem</name>
        <id>2345123465</id>        
    <data>
        <name>Vincent Dagpin</name>
        <id>56783567245</id>        
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>Vrynxzent Kamote</name>
        <id>3456824567</id>        
    </data>
    <paging>
        <next>nextURLHere</next>
    </paging>
</friends>
```

Comment: Hint: What would you expect the resulting XML to look like?  Also, I'm curious about why you'd want to do this.  JSON is just as expressive as XML (if not more so), so why bother converting it?

Comment: because some instance, i do not know what are my json contains. i can't parse it to any object type since i do not know what properties they have. make sense?

Comment: his point is, even if you can't map it to an object, why not leave it as json?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you need is a root element in your json I think.  which is what XML needs.

which I think you can do by

```
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "friends");
```

Comment: you mean 

**XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);**

will be initialized to have root element?

Comment: oh.. i think, i just missed this string parameter for root element.. thanks.. :)