# C# - How to convert complex json to XML with name and value property to tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, wcf

Trying convert json to XML with **JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(Json.ToString())** and its works but not expected,

**First Exapmle:**

JSON :

> "Emailid": ""

Converted XML :

```
<Emailid></Emailid>
```

First example working as expected

**Second Example:**

JSON :

> "ProposalDate": {
>                               "Name": "Proposal Date",
>                               "Value": "06/05/2019"
>                           }

Converted XML :

```
<ProposalDate>
    <Name>Proposal Date</Name>
    <Value>06/05/2019</Value>
</ProposalDate>
```

**Expected XML for second example:**

```
<ProposalDate Name="Proposal Date" Value="06/05/2019" />
```

but for second example want ProposalDate tag with **Name** and **Value** property.
What should i do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770630/json-to-xml-conversion-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the above links at all, user is asking for a way to convert to XML having the values as attributes rather than child tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deserialize JSON to a class first, apply `[XmlAttribute]` to the class properties and then serialize the class to XML. See the [XmlAttributeAttribute Class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Your class would look something like this:

```
public class ProposalDate
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing JSON to object and serializing object to XML are well documented, and examples easily found.

Comment: Great bro...working as expected...Thanx for your valuable response :)